# Как создать рандом на C++

Tags: c++

Учусь писать на с++ но застрял на коде создания рандома. Как его реализовать?

Comment: Различных генераторов "рандомных" значений - десятки. Ваш вопрос слишком обширен в связи с этим.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Новый способ (С++11) - использовать библиотеку [`random`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/)

Тривиальный пример использования:

```
#include <random>
std::default_random_engine generator;
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(1,6);
int dice_roll = distribution(generator);  // generates number in the range 1..6
```

---

Старый способ (пришедший из С), который не рекомендуется к использованию в современном C++ коде:

```
#include <stdlib.h> // srand, rand
#include <time.h>   // time

srand(time(0));
int random_number = rand();
```

Comment: спасибо за либу)

Comment: Причем, функцию srand(time(0)); нужно вызвать только один раз во всей программе.

Comment: Сначала нужно приводить решение на C++11, а потом уже с оговорками и маленьким шрифтом этот устаревший метод `rand()`. И уж никак не наоборот.

Comment: @ixSci на С++11 решение может быть слишком разным, в зависимости от нужд спрашивающего. Но скопипасчу я свой код, а ему совсем другое распределение нужно. В руководстве же есть масса примеров на все (стандартные) случаи жизни.

Comment: ну, с `rand` у Вас подобной дилеммы не возникло, а там распределение вообще не указано, как и то, как правильно можно использовать `rand` чтобы он хоть какое-то подобие равномерного распределения выдавал. Зачем плодить устаревшие решение?

Comment: @ixSci, как раз `rand()` предполагает единственный вариант использования. Так то Вы правы, но я не могу придумать *универсальный* пример использования `random`, поэтому ограничился названием библиотеки и ссылкой. Иначе нужно писать полное руководство. Так лучше? )))

Comment: Теперь лучше, да.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <random>
#include <ctime>
srand(time(0))   //без этого будут одни и те же значения
a = rand()%10+1; //рандом от 1 до 10
```