# Как создать рандомайзер вещественных чисел в C++?

Tags: c++, случайные-числа

Нашел два способа в этом вопросе [Как создать рандом на C++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/575156/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-c/575162), но они оба касаются целого типа, в то время как у меня на вход как диапазон рандомайзера поступают вещественные числа с неопределенным количеством знаков после запятой. Не подскажите, как сделать такой рандомайзер?

Answer (score 4):

Почти точно так же:

```
random_device rd;
default_random_engine gen(rd());
uniform_real_distribution<> dis(
                2.7182818,    // Ваш диапазон - начало
                3.1415926);   // и конец
for (int n = 0; n < 10; ++n) {

    cout << dis(gen) << ' ';

}
```

Можно указывать диапазон каждый раз при вызове:

```
default_random_engine gen(random_device{}());

uniform_real_distribution<> r;
cout << r(gen,
          uniform_real_distribution<>::param_type(2.7182818,
                                                  3.1415926));
```

P.S. Если планируете работать со случайными числами *всерьез* - забывайте о `rand/srand`, работайте со стандартной библиотекой `<random>`..

Comment: Большое спасибо за этот способ!

Comment: спасибо выражается в виде нажимания на стрелочку сверху или галочку снизу или и то и другое...

Comment: @Harry хотел спросить, почему дефолт а не вихрь Мерсенна? Он же вроде проходит больше тестов )

Comment: @Maggot Потому что в большинстве случаев, как я понимаю, дефолтный он и есть :) А всерьез - потому что это дело разработчиков библиотеки, сделать дефолтным наиболее универсальный, подходящий и так далее генератор. Использовать тот или иной конкретный - это уже под конкретную задачу, когда точно известно, что нужен именно этот, а не какой-то иной. А когда задача "вообще" - то и генератор "вообще". Мое imho, понятно.

Comment: На тот момент это было мое первое сообщение на ресурсе и репутация не позволяла просто нажать на стрелочку. К тому же, мне кажется, приятнее слышать слова благодарности...

Comment: Понимаете, если есть ответ, который устраивает - правила хорошего тона говорят о том, что его надо принять - тем самым вопрос будет помечен как отвеченный, т.е. другие пользователи при поиске будут знать, что здесь есть ответ. Да и "слова благодарности" - они именно такие: стрелочка вверх и птичка принятого ответа. Вместе - как "большое спасибо" :) Так что если ответ вас устроил - нажмите, пожалуйста, на "птичку" рядом с ним.

Answer (score 2):

```
srand (static_cast <unsigned> (time(0)));
float x = min + static_cast <float> (rand()) /( static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX/(max-min)));
```

`srand (static_cast <unsigned> (time(0)));` - задаем `seed`

`min` - значение от

`max` - значение до

Если нужно от `0.0` до `1.0`, то убираете коэффициенты `min` и `max-min`, по аналогии и если от `0.0` до требуемого значения

Comment: Большое спасибо! Оно работает!

Comment: seed кастить не объязательно(скорее это просто ухудшает читабельность, и не приносит пользу), знаменатель тоже кастить не нужно, поскольку  float / int   вернет float.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan если max и min float, разве нет?

Comment: а разве  `srand(time(0));  min + rand() * (max - min) / RAND_MAX` не дает тот же результат?