# не рандомный рандом

Tags: c++, случайные-числа

При использовании `std::default_random_engine`, а именно в связке с разными типами дистрибьюторов (а именно : `std::uniform_int_distribution` / `std::normal_distribution` / `std::binomial_distribution`). Рандом выдает всегда 0.

Пример кода:

```
.... кусок кода где я пытаюсь дать "астеройду" совершенно рандомную позицию на экране.
auto leftScreenSide = diceRoll(0,2);
auto upScreenSide = diceRoll(0,2);
auto leftBound = SCREEN_WIDTH / 2 - 60;
auto rightBound = SCREEN_WIDTH / 2 + 60;
auto upperBound = SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2 + 60;
auto lowerBound = SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2 - 60;

auto _x = 0;
auto _y = 0;
if(leftScreenSide == 0){
    _x = diceRoll(0, leftBound);
}
else{
    _x = diceRoll(rightBound, SCREEN_WIDTH);
}

if(upScreenSide == 0){
    _y = diceRoll(0, upperBound);

}
else{
    _y = diceRoll(lowerBound, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
}

.... собственно сам кусок метода diceRoll
int Asteroid::diceRoll(int lowerBound, int upperBound) {
    std::default_random_engine generator;
    std::binomial_distribution<int> distribution(lowerBound,upperBound);
    int diceRoll =  distribution(generator);
    return diceRoll;
}
```

Я так понимаю что этот ГПСЧ (генератор псевдослучайных чисел) пытается по средствам разных типов дистрибьюторов обеспечить более менее равномерное покрытие (естественно каждый дистрибьютор покрывается по своему). И надо каким либо образом "кэшировать" этот генератор, если хочется "равномерное" покрытие. Но вот почему всегда первое значение которое отдает генератор - 0 ? Скорее всего я делаю что то не правильно.

p.s:

перед тем как задать вопрос читал это -

[Как создать рандом на C++ [закрыт]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/575156/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-c/575162#575162)

[cplusplus.com random](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам бы стоило инициализировать ваш генератор чем-то действительно случайным. Ну, как в старом варианте с `rand()` советуют перед началом работы вызвать что-то типа `srand(time(0))`.

Вы можете использовать для этого `random_device`. Типа

```
default_random_engine generator(random_device{}());
binomial_distribution<int> distribution(5,0.5);
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) cout << distribution(generator) << endl;
```

Только вот что вы хотите получить тут?

```
std::binomial_distribution<int> distribution(lowerBound,upperBound);
```

Параметры `binomial_distribution` - это максимальное значение t и вероятность p:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Непохоже, что ваши параметры описывают именно эти значения. Может, вам на самом деле нужно [`uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution)?

Answer (score 3):

В методе `Asteroid::diceRoll` экземпляр `generator`создаётся локально при каждом выполнении метода и разрушается при выходе из него. Инициализирующей последовательности нет, соответственно каждый вновь созданный экземпляр генератора инициализируется неким значением по умолчанию `default_seed` и всегда выдаёт одну и ту же последовательность при каждом вызове.

Вид конкретного генератора для `std::default_random_engine`зависит от реализации.
Вполне возможно, что используется и `std::mersenne_twister_engine`. Для `std::mersenne_twister_engine::default_seed` имеет значение `5489u`.

Можно написать `static std::default_random_engine generator`. Тогда при последовательных вызовах `Asteroid::diceRoll` будет получать различные значения, но от запуска к запуску программы последовательность будет повторяться. Часто это и бывает нужно, чтобы повторять псевдослучайные, но те же самые события, например, для отладки.

Не стоит создавать много генераторов, а следует применять один глобальный объект, или, по крайней мере, `thread_local`, чтобы не пришлось использовать mutex.
Если же будут использоваться несколько генераторов, то вполне возможно, что их совместные значения окажутся более зависимы, чем значения полученные от единственного генератора.

Для иллюстрации возьмём предельный случай: два генератора инициализированы одним и тем же значением и выдают совершенно одинаковые последовательности. Так, например, координаты точек, которые будут генерироваться парой раздельных, но синхронных генераторов для `x` и `y`, все окажутся на диагонали. Обычно такой вырожденный случай наблюдается редко, но зависимости всё равно наблюдаются при глубоком анализе.

Естественно, что лучше самому управлять инициализацией экземпляров этих генераторов.
Например, для отладки устанавливать свой seed, а для реальной работы - использовать какой-нибудь источник меняющихся данных для `std::seed_seq`, например, время/дату для основного генератора, а сгенерированную уже этим генератором последовательность - для `thread_local` генераторов в других потоках.

Надеюсь, что ошибка аргументов конструктора `std::binomial_distribution` (или неверного выбора вида распределения), на которую уже указали в других ответах, может быть исправлена самостоятельно.

Answer (score 1):

Создаем высоко-качественную последовательность случайных целых чисел на основе алгоритма "Вихрь Мерсенна":

```
#include <ctime>
#include <random> 

int array[100];
std::mt19937 gen(std::time(0)); //создание объекта класса и закидывание в конструктор зерна
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> diapazon(0, 10); //задание диапазона случайных целых чисел 0...10
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    array[i] = diapazon(gen); //генерация массива качественных случ. чисел в диапазоне 0...10
```

Если нужен 64 битный генератор, используй `std::mt19937_64`

Если нужны случайные числа с плавающей точкой, используй `std::uniform_real_distribution<double>`

P.S.: [Почитать про Вихрь Мерсенна тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%85%D1%80%D1%8C_%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0)

Comment: Лучше использовать [`std::random_device`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device) вместо `std::time`